# Como fazer o PHP aceitar acentuação?

Tags: php

Como posso fazer o PHP aceitar acentuações como " ´ " e "^". Ele teria que funcionar nessa lista que eu criei em PHP (Esse não é o código completo da lista).

```
<td><?php echo $dado['RM'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $dado['Nome'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $dado['Email'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $dado['Turma_ID'];?></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coloque o trecho abaixo na parte da sua página que tem o HTML, lá onde tem o HEAD.

```
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
```

Coloque também no seu código PHP em cada linha que imprimir dados, mas teste algo asim:

```
<td><?php echo utf8_decode($dado['RM']);?></td>
```

Ou

```
<td><?php echo utf8_encode($dado['RM']);?></td>
```

No meu início com PHP, HTML, CSS, Javascript e etc... usei muito esta fonte de consulta:

[W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com)

Comment: Muito obrigado, foi! Você é muito bom em PHP, meus parabéns, e você tem razão, estou dependendo muito do StackOverflow, entretanto eu não faço isso por falta de vontade de pesquisar, é que eu realmente estou muito perdido com PHP e meu inglês não é muito bom... Mas sim, eu uso o w3schools, tanto que eu aprendi bastante de CSS lá.

Comment: Vinicius, fica tranquilo... usar o StackOverflow é normal para todo programador, te mandei o W3Schools mesmo, só para fins de estudo futuramente.
Faça perguntas aqui sempre que quiser e rpecisar!

Comment: Obrigado Luis! Tenha um ótimo dia!